# Como usar DrawToBitmap no WPF para tirar print da tela?

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf

Segue código funcional do `WinForms`:

```
Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(label1.Width, label1.Height);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, label1.Width, label1.Height);
rect = label1.ClientRectangle;
label1.DrawToBitmap(pic, rect);
// pic.Save("C:\\, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

O código acima tira printscreen do `label1` e salva a imagem no local.

Como faço a mesma do `WinForms` para `WPF` ?

Segue o código da tentativa do `WPF`:

```
Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(label1);

RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap((Int32)bounds.Width, (Int32)bounds.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();

using (DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    VisualBrush visualBrush = new VisualBrush(label1);
    context.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(), bounds.Size));
}

renderTarget.Render(visual);
PngBitmapEncoder bitmapEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
bitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));

using (Stream stm = File.Create(@"C:\Users\Matheus Miranda\Desktop\TESTE"))
{
    bitmapEncoder.Save(stm);
}
```

Alguma solução ?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df4db537-a201-4ab4-bb7e-db38a5c2b6e0/wpf-equivalent-of-winforms-controldrawtobitmap?forum=wpf

Comment: Acabei de resolver problema: trocar isso `@"C:\Users\Matheus Miranda\Desktop\TESTE"` para `@"C:\Users\Matheus Miranda\Desktop\TESTE"\nomedafoto.jpg`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Tu sabe como deixar a imagem de alta qualidade ?

Comment: não cara... nem mexo com wpf =/, só tentei ajudar com o link aí

Comment: Seria interessante postar uma resposta para a pergunta não ficar pendente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido:

Troca essa linha `@"C:\Users\Matheus Miranda\Desktop\TESTE"` por `@"C:\Users\Matheus Miranda\Desktop\TESTE"\nomedafoto.jpg`

Esqueci especificar nome do arquivo.